# Intellij Idea's Project view doesn't show all project files

Tags: intellij-idea

a colleague of mine checked out a git repository from github which is an assignment for college. But he can't see all relevant files and folders in the project view. Any ideas for solving this issue would be highly appreciated...

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you and best regards
Philipp

Comment: IntelliJ does not show folders like .git etc but I have never had any problems to access files I really needed in IntelliJ. Can you give examples of those missing files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely the project was imported into IDEA, but it's not a pure Java project.

Note that non-Java projects cannot be imported from the existing sources using the Import option.

You should create a new project, select the appropriate module type and then point to the existing directory with the code when creating the module.

Other options are to import from Maven/Eclipse/Gradle.

There is a [known issue logged](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91446).

If it's not the case, please share a sample project (zipped) that will reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I tried importing a JRuby on Rails project into IntelliJ and it didn't show many of the directories and files. Like you said, creating a new project works. IntelliJ needs to show the root folder in the Project view, not some of the subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, project `.iml` file was not found. So I imported project to idea, and it imported project and created `.iml` file. All files and folders are visible now.